# Beginner tips on using plyr to calculate year-over-year change across groups

Tags: r, dataframe, plyr

I am new to plyr (and R) and looking for a little help to get started.  Using the baseball dataset as an exaple, how could I calculate the year-over-year (yoy) change in "at batts" by league and team (lg and team)?

```
library(plyr)
df1 <- aggregate(ab~year+lg+team, FUN=sum, data=baseball)
```

After doing a little aggregating to simplify the data fame, the data looks like this:

```
head(df1)

  year lg team   ab
  1884 UA  ALT  108
  1997 AL  ANA 1703
  1998 AL  ANA 1502
  1999 AL  ANA  660
  2000 AL  ANA   85
  2001 AL  ANA  219
```

I would like to end up with someting like this

```
  year lg team   ab yoy
  1997 AL  ANA 1703  NA
  1998 AL  ANA 1502  -201
  1999 AL  ANA  660  -842
  2000 AL  ANA   85  -575
  2001 AL  ANA  219  134
```

I started by writign the following function, which I think is wrong:

```
yoy.func <- function(df) {
  lag <- c(df$ab[-1],0)
  cur <- c(df$ab[1],0)
  df$yoy <- cur -lag
  return(df)
}
```

Without sucess, I used the following code to attempt return the yoy change.

```
df2 <- ddply(df1, .(lg, team), yoy.func)
```

Any guidance woud be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Well done with the reproducible example and an excellent first pass!  The problem is the length of your two vectors in the function.  `lag` will be == `nrow(df)` while `cur` will be == `nrow(df) + 1`.  If you just subtract `df$ab - lag` you should be all set. (the only missing piece is to confirm you've got consecutive years.)  I'd also look at `rollapply` from the `zoo` package.

Comment: Justin, Thanks for the suggestion to look at rollapply.  But, to clarify, were you suggesting it as a tool to ensure that the years are consectuive?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know you asked for a "plyr"-specific solution, but for the sake of sharing, here is an alternative approach in base R. In my opinion, I find the base R approach just as "readable". And, at least in this particular case, it's a lot faster!

```
output <- within(df1, {
  yoy <- ave(ab, team, lg, FUN = function(x) c(NA, diff(x)))
})
head(output)
#   year lg team   ab  yoy
# 1 1884 UA  ALT  108   NA
# 2 1997 AL  ANA 1703   NA
# 3 1998 AL  ANA 1502 -201
# 4 1999 AL  ANA  660 -842
# 5 2000 AL  ANA   85 -575
# 6 2001 AL  ANA  219  134

library(rbenchmark)

benchmark(DDPLY = {
  ddply(df1, .(team, lg), mutate ,
        yoy = c(NA, diff(ab)))
}, WITHIN = {
  within(df1, {
    yoy <- ave(ab, team, lg, FUN = function(x) c(NA, diff(x)))
  })
}, columns = c("test", "replications", "elapsed", 
               "relative", "user.self"))
#     test replications elapsed relative user.self
# 1  DDPLY          100  10.675    4.974    10.609
# 2 WITHIN          100   2.146    1.000     2.128
```

### Update: `data.table`

If your data are very large, check out `data.table`. Even with this example, you'll find a good speedup in relative terms. Plus the syntax is super compact and, in my opinion, easily readable.

```
library(plyr)
df1 <- aggregate(ab~year+lg+team, FUN=sum, data=baseball)
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(df1)
DT
#       year lg team   ab
#    1: 1884 UA  ALT  108
#    2: 1997 AL  ANA 1703
#    3: 1998 AL  ANA 1502
#    4: 1999 AL  ANA  660
#    5: 2000 AL  ANA   85
#   ---                  
# 2523: 1895 NL  WSN  839
# 2524: 1896 NL  WSN  982
# 2525: 1897 NL  WSN 1426
# 2526: 1898 NL  WSN 1736
# 2527: 1899 NL  WSN  787
```

Now, look at this concise solution:

```
DT[, yoy := c(NA, diff(ab)), by = "team,lg"]
DT
#       year lg team   ab  yoy
#    1: 1884 UA  ALT  108   NA
#    2: 1997 AL  ANA 1703   NA
#    3: 1998 AL  ANA 1502 -201
#    4: 1999 AL  ANA  660 -842
#    5: 2000 AL  ANA   85 -575
#   ---                       
# 2523: 1895 NL  WSN  839  290
# 2524: 1896 NL  WSN  982  143
# 2525: 1897 NL  WSN 1426  444
# 2526: 1898 NL  WSN 1736  310
# 2527: 1899 NL  WSN  787 -949
```

Comment: thanks Amanda, great idea.  I'm pretty new to R and am trying to learn Plyr but in no way wed to using it so I appreciate your suggestion.  Is there anyone from that Plyr camp that offer any reasons why Plyr might be a better solution?

Comment: @MikeTP, I'm afraid that if someone from the "data.table" camp comes along with a `data.table` solution (which would be very easy), you'd be changing accepted answers again! I think it really comes down to preference and consistency of syntax. `plyr` and `data.table` both have their own syntax that might be a bit different from a base R approach, and for some, the constructs might just seem more natural.

Comment: @MikeTP, I also usually just like to add base R solutions whenever possible, since I sometimes find them to be quite overlooked.

Comment: @Amanda. lol, thanks.  Speaking as a beginner, with so many packages, its sometimes hard to decide witch packages/solutions I should learn first.  I have been using quite a bit of ggplot so I figured learning plyr would be a good additional staple package to learn.  However, your answer makes a compelling case.

Comment: @MikeTP, added `data.table` for you. Do some benchmarks if you'd like, or at least wrap the command with a `system.time()` to see how it compares. By the way, it's ANanda (actually a male name!) not AManda ;)

Comment: @Ananda, Thanks.  My apologies for the repeated typo on your name.

Answer (score 5):

How about using diff():

```
df <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = '  year lg team   ab
  1884 UA  ALT  108
  1997 AL  ANA 1703
  1998 AL  ANA 1502
  1999 AL  ANA  660
  2000 AL  ANA   85
  2001 AL  ANA  219')
require(plyr)
ddply(df, .(team, lg), mutate ,
      yoy = c(NA, diff(ab)))
#   year lg team   ab  yoy
1 1884 UA  ALT  108   NA
2 1997 AL  ANA 1703   NA
3 1998 AL  ANA 1502 -201
4 1999 AL  ANA  660 -842
5 2000 AL  ANA   85 -575
6 2001 AL  ANA  219  134
```

Comment: This is a nice, concise answer.  EDi is exactly right.  Note that you have to join the 'diff' function with an 'NA' value, or you'll get weird errors.  If it helps, you can keep with the 'ddply' function wrapper and load your data like so: `df <- ddply(baseball, .(year, lg, team), summarize, ab=sum(ab))`